# can't pick date in angular date picker

Tags: angular, datepicker, flatpickr, angular-calendar

I'm using angularx-flatpickr for date picker

i can not pick a date in date picker ,
it is showing me ban icon when i hover over the date
[image: datepicker-image]

html :

```
<label class="col-md-12">From Date</label>
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" mwlFlatpickr [convertModelValue]="true" [enableTime]="false"
                    dateFormat="F j, Y" altFormat="F j, Y" formControlName="fromdate" placeholder="Not set" />
```

Edit :
its showing "flatpickr-disabled" when i inspect the element

```
<span class="flatpickr-day flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="January 2, 2021">2</span>
```

but can't get from where it is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

done , i got the answer .

it's banning me from select date because of

`dayElement.classList.add("flatpickr-disabled");`
in index.js file in flatpickr /dist/esm/index.js

so i simply removed the flatpickr-disabled

Comment: Great @user shah

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this will enable the control, however thanks to your great hint, I followed the logic and it turned out to be

```
        const dateIsEnabled = isEnabled(date, true), dayElement = createElement("span", "flatpickr-day " + className, date.getDate().toString());
```

Is the one that causes the control to become disabled, the way it parses the date is not correct,
Basically that would help enable the control, but won't help the problem setting the value (from within the code)

Comment: I am guessing you are using Angular 11+, which apparently not compatible with angularx-flatpick (yet)

Answer (score 0):

I had also all dates disabled. Try specify "enable" range. That helped me. (NG11)

````
flatpickerOptions: FlatpickrDefaultsInterface = {
 enable: [
      {
        from: '2019-04-01',
        to: '2025-05-01'
      }
    ]
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I am using angular 12, I got it fixed using this option in the module

```
FlatpickrModule.forRoot({
    enable: [
      { from: '1900-01-01', to: '2500-12-31'}
    ]
})
```

Comment: You can also try
`FlatpickrModule.forRoot({
  enable: [
    { from: new Date(1900, 0, 1), to: new Date(2500, 11, 31)}
  ]
})`